# How can i undo my code changes after committing the code locally?

Tags: git

How can i undo my code changes after committing locally which should not affect my currently existing staged changes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but probably using `git reset`. Consider creating a backup copy of your repository before messing around with it since you're still learning.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear to me what you're situation is. Maybe the output of `git status` would help clarify things?

Comment: what i am trying to say is there are two sets of code. one set of code is what i have commited locally i.e to my local branch another set of code is whatever the changes i did after commiting the first set of code locally. so now here is my question. i need to revert back the changes that i have already committed i.e first set of code this should not affect my second set of code changes that was currently present in unstaged changes. if i do git reset my total code changes in the branch will get reverted i do not need this

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to do that.

1. Get the diff

   ```
   git diff --staged > staged.diff
   ```
2. Reset HEAD to one commit before that particular commit.

   ```
   git reset --hard <your last correct commitID>
   ```
3. Apply diff back

   ```
   git apply staged.diff
   ```
4. Resolve conflicts

Comment: Rather than storing the staged changes in a diff file, you can [put them in the stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning).

Comment: @Schwern, it's another way of doing it. But, having diff is safer.

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan Can I ask in what way it's safer?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "staged changes" you mean changes which have added to the index with `git add` but have not commited. The easiest way to preserve local changes whether or not you have staged them is with

```
git stash
```

or

```
git stash save "Some message"
```

After you do this, you can do

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

to reset the current branch to the previous commit. Replace `HEAD~` with any commit reference, such as a SHA1 hash or another branch name, if you like.

Now to restore the changes which you stashed earlier, just do

```
git stash pop
```

to remove them from the stash or

```
git stash apply
```

to only apply them to the local copy.